# Angular mat-tree with ng-template

Tags: angular

```
<app-test-node [nestedDataSource]="nestedDataSource" [nestedTreeControl]="nestedTreeControl" [template]="nodetemp" [template2]="nestednodetemp">
</app-test-node>


<ng-template let-node="data" #nodetemp>
  <li class="mat-tree-node">
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.filename}}:  {{node.type}}
  </li>
</ng-template>

<ng-template let-node="data" #nestednodetemp>
  <li>
    <div class="mat-tree-node">
      <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
              [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
          {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
      {{node.filename}}
    </div>
    <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

Trying to pass tree node template to the following component:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl" class="example-tree">

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
     <ng-container  [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data: node}"></ng-container>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
    <ng-container  [ngTemplateOutlet]="template2" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data: node}"></ng-container>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>

</mat-tree>
```

the problem is the matTreeNodeToggle directive, when i add it to the button in the template i get the following error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatNestedTreeNode ->
>   CdkTree]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatNestedTreeNode ->
>   CdkTree]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for CdkTree!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:1062)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8369)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:9057)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:9422)

Comment: This is a dependency injection issue. MatNestedTreeNodeis is not provided by your component or one of its parent. Can you post the `.ts` of your component?

Comment: this code is sligthly modified material tree example (https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples) the outer ts is original not modified and the ts of the container is `@Input()
  nestedTreeControl: NestedTreeControl<FileNode>;

  @Input()
  nestedDataSource:  MatTreeNestedDataSource<FileNode>;

  @Input()
  template;

  @Input()
  template2;

  hasNestedChild = (_: number, nodeData: FileNode) => !nodeData.type;`

Comment: The thing is when i remove the matTreeNodeToggle directive from the ng-template button it works fine

Comment: @Alex did you find the problem?

Answer (score 8):

You probably solved this by now, but for other people who ran into the same problem: The directive is nothing more than a click event which calls toggle ([src](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/tree/toggle.ts)). This means you can simply replace the `matTreeNodeToggle` with `(click)="treeControl.toggle(node)"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! you are the men!!

saved me hours of invistigation!!!

Comment: Peculiar. When I tried taking control of this with my own function, it always got _two_ events; one that expanded the clicked node, and a second that collapsed that node's highest-level parent in the tree. Not sure what caused that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `CdkTree` and `CdkTreeNode` in your component's providers list.